# Is it possible to bake an image texture of an object with geometry nodes modifier?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, geometry-nodes, texture-baking

I followed this tutorial to make an object like its made of legos and I was wondering if it is possible to transform it to a mesh with baked texture image. I finally found how to convert it to a mesh with "Realize instances", the problem is that when applying the geoemtry node modifier the color info is lost; and here is my question, is it possible to bake the color of the lego object to transfer it to the new mesh?

Here is a comment of the tutorial creator explaining the way of doing it but can anyone elaborate please?

[image]

I attach images with all the setup. Thank you in advance. I am using the version 3.4.0 of Blender.

[image: Shader setup]

[image: Geometry node setup]

[image: Object with geometry node without applying "Realize instances"]
Object with geometry node without applying "Realize instances"

[image: Object converted to mesh]

Mesh with realize instances applied.

[image]

Original object.

Comment: To bake the texture you have to unwrap the UV of the mesh.

Comment: yep, UV unwrap the "realized" model. Then you can bake the diffuse color from the GN model to the realized model (bake option *[X] Selected to Active*).

Comment: Your GN model has an attribute named UVMap. So after you converted it to a mesh you can convert this attribute to a real UV Map (https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQAWW.jpg) and use it in the material node setup.